# calculate sum of limit using riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, power-series, riemann-integration

calculate this sum of limit using riemann sum, $\lim_\limits {n\to \infty}  \frac{1}{n}{\left({\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)}}\right)}^{1/n} $

\begin{align*}
&=\ln  \frac{1}{n}+\ln\left ( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}{\log 2n+\log (2n-1)+....+\log 1-(\log n+\log(n-1)+...+\log 1)} \right)\\ 
&=**\log \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(n+k)\\&= \frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\ln \frac{1}{n}+log(n+k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)\right]**\\
 .
\end{align*}

$\frac{1}{n}*{{\log 2n+\log (2n-1)+....+\log 1-(\log n+ \log(n-1)+....+\log 1)}}$
i was confused how can i get the starred part,   how to manipulate it to $\sum \ln(n+k)$?  is this using property of power series? can someone explain this so clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compute the log and do some algebra:
$$
\log \frac{1}{n}{\left({\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)}}\right)}^{1/n}
=
\log \left[ 2 \times \left( \frac{n!}{n!} \times \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n-1)(2n)}{2^n \times n^{n}} \right)^{1/n} \right]
,
$$
which is
$$
\log 2 + \frac{1}{n} \log \left( \frac{n+1}{2n} \times \frac{n+2}{2n} \times \cdots \times \frac{2n}{2n} \right)
,
$$
and rewrinting as a sum
$$
\log 2 + 2 \times \left[ \frac{1}{2n} \left( \log \frac{n+1}{2n} + \log\frac{n+2}{2n} + \cdots + \log\frac{2n}{2n} \right) \right]
.
$$
Inside the bracket we have a Riemann sum for
$$
\int_{1/2}^1 \log x\, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{-1+\log 2}2
. 
$$
Therefore the log of the limit is
$$
\log 2 + \log 2 - 1
$$
so the limit is
$$
4/e
.
$$

Comment: @user33469 thnkyou for answering my question,$\log 2 + 2 \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \log \frac{k}{n}$ but really have no idea how to get this, can you explain how you get the sigma notation? from this $\frac{1}{n}*{{\log 2n+\log (2n-1)+....+\log 1-(\log n+ \log(n-1)+....+\log 1)}}$ and why there is 2?

Comment: @fiksx So you wanto to study riemann sums and have no clue what properties the $\ln$ has? You really have to look them up!

Comment: Sorry it was $\log\frac{k}{2n}$ inside the sum. Apart from that, I have expanded and replaced $\sum$ by ``$\cdots$''. But as pointed out by Niklas, if you don't understand $\sum$ than you will have a hard time understanding Riemann sums.

Comment: @user334639 thanks!! i just wondering from $2n, 2n-1,2n-2, n+1,n ,2,1$ and left part was $n+1,n,...$  but im not quite understand with $2n$ in denominator, and why you have to multiply it by 2?

Comment: I made it more explicit about what happened to the n, n-1, n-2, etc.The question asks you to use Riemman sum, so you try to make it look like one. That's why we multiply and divide by n and 2 and again by 2.